# Openstack multiple site cloud orchestration

Tags: cloud, openstack, openstack-heat

Hei, I am looking to orchestrate infrastructure using HEAT templates on multiple OpenStack sites. One easy way is to divide the template and run on sites separately. But, is there any way that I can create a single template for multi-site orchestration

Comment: What do you mean by "multi-site"? Do you want to write only one Heat template that includes two or three different kinds of deployment? Correct me if I miss-understood.

Comment: hei multi-site mean two open stack cloud deployment at two different geographical locations

Answer (score 0):

AFAK it is possible to deploy openstack with ansible. Think like ansible-instance, heat-openstack site.Ansible deploys openstacks with HOT in it.